# Change color of unselected icon in TabView (SwiftUI)

Tags: colors, swiftui

How can i change color of unselected icon (on screenshot) in TabView (SwiftUI)? Because this icon is invisible

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `TabBarAccessor` from my solution to [Programmatically detect Tab Bar or TabView height in SwiftUI](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Find_TabBar_height.md) to change what you need as in below demo.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image]

```
TabView {
    Text("First View")
        .background(TabBarAccessor { tabBar in
            tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red
        })
        .tabItem { Image(systemName: "1.circle") }
        .tag(0)
    Text("Second View")
        .tabItem { Image(systemName: "2.circle") }
        .tag(1)
}
```

**Update:** alternate via appearance also works

[image: demo]

```
init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.green
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Can i do something like that in 'init()' method of my View Struct? Example for changing background 'init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = MyColor.blackcolorUI
    }'

Comment: somehow didn't work for me :( neither first nor second option. as if it wouldn't have a UITabBar under the hood but view debugger does show UITabBar

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make sure your image has the desired color for the unselected state, track which item is selected and then toggle rendering mode `.template` for it.

```swift
// Create helper extension
extension Image {
    @ViewBuilder
    fileprivate func setRenderingMode(selected: Bool) -> some View {
        if selected {
            self.renderingMode(.template)
        } else {
            self.renderingMode(.original)
        }
    }
}

// Then in your TabView

struct MyTab: View {
    enum TabItem {
        case tab1
        case tab2
        case tab3
    }

    @State var selectedTab = TabItem.tab1

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("Tab Content 1")
                .tabItem {
                    Image("tabimage1")
                        .setRenderingMode(selected: selectedTab == .tab1)
                }.tag(TabItem.tab1)

            Text("Tab Content 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image("tabimage2")
                        .setRenderingMode(selected: selectedTab == .tab2)
                }.tag(TabItem.tab2)

            Text("Tab Content 3")
                .tabItem {
                    Image("tabimage3")
                        .setRenderingMode(selected: selectedTab == .tab3)
                }.tag(TabItem.tab3)
        }.tint(Color.red)
    }
}
```

What this does is that when selected, the rendering mode changes to template therefore tinting the image with the tint color. When not selected, it renders in the default color (e.g. black).