# How can I change the unselected state color in TabView, for SwiftUI, using the rendering(.template), or even without it?

Tags: swift, swiftui

so here is my current code:
I am trying to make it so when I select the icon in my tabView, the AccentColor is utilized for the selected states. And, that the unselected icons be color white.
When I use  .renderingMode(.template), it makes that the unselected states are a default grey, which I dont want.

I have also attempted in init to do:
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white

But that also didnt work.
Can someone help me?
I attempted the solution in: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404684/change-color-of-unselected-icon-in-tabview-swiftui) and also was unsuccessful, Like the code compiled, but the color would remain in grey. I believe maybe with néwer versions of Swift and Xcode the solution in the link above doesnt work anymore? it is weird...

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = "chat"  

    init() {
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.04, green: 0.27, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1)
        
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image("ic-settings")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .foregroundColor(selectedTab == "settings" ? Color("AccentColor") : Color.white)
                }
                .tag("settings")

            NavigationView {
                ChatView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image("ic-chat-bubble")
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .foregroundColor(selectedTab == "chat" ? Color("AccentColor") : Color.white)
            }
            .tag("chat")
            
            AnalyticsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image("ic-analytics")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .foregroundColor(selectedTab == "analytics" ? Color("AccentColor") : Color.white)
                }
                .tag("analytics")
        }
    }
}



#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

I am expecting to have the icons in white/original color when unselected, instead of the default grey of .template