# Why does changing unselected tab color in Swift UI doesnt work through appearence anymore?

Tags: swift, swiftui

so I am trying to change the unselected tab color in a tabview in SwiftUI, however, by doing this in the init:
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
Does not work, as it used to.

Does anyone know what happened and what I can do to work around this now that it doesnt work anymore?
I tried doing:

```
 TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image("ic-settings")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .foregroundColor(selectedTab == "settings" ? Color("AccentColor") : Color.white)
                }
                .tag("settings")

            NavigationView {
                ChatView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image("ic-chat-bubble")
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .foregroundColor(selectedTab == "chat" ? Color("AccentColor") : Color.white)
            }
```

But this also made no difference, and the unselected tab icon are still the default grey from .template rendering.

I tried doing What is up there, and I also tried using TabBarAccessor, but it also seem that it is deprecated in most recent version of XCODE.
I just want to make the unselected icons in the tab view White/original color, while maintaining the AccentColor, for the selected tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor` works for me.

If you want more control, see [Change color of unselected icon in TabView (SwiftUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404684/change-color-of-unselected-icon-in-tabview-swiftui) , the answer to your previous question.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = "chat"

    init() {
         UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.green
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("SettingView")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .foregroundColor(selectedTab == "settings" ? Color.green : Color.white)
                }
                .tag("settings")

            NavigationView {
              //  ChatView()
                Text("ChatView")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house")
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .foregroundColor(selectedTab == "chat" ? Color.green : Color.white)
            }
            .tag("chat")
            
            Text("AnalyticsView")
         //   AnalyticsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "info")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .foregroundColor(selectedTab == "analytics" ? Color.green : Color.white)
                }
                .tag("analytics")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So Appearently the problem is that I am also using 
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance

And that makes it basically ignore the unselectedTintColor?

Comment: With appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = UIColor.white,
I solved it!